# Java initialize 2d arraylist

Tags: java, dynamic, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I want to do 2D dynamic ArrayList example:

```
[1][2][3]
[4][5][6]
[7][8][9]
```

and i used this code:

```
 ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> group = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        group.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(1, 2, 3));
```

how should i initialize this arraylist?

Comment: Initialize the arraylist as in?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it is not necessary for the inner lists to be specifically `ArrayList`s, one way of doing such initialization in Java 7 would be as follows:

```
ArrayList<List<Integer>> group = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
group.add(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
group.add(Arrays.asList(4, 5, 6));
group.add(Arrays.asList(7, 8, 9));
for (List<Integer> list : group) {
    for (Integer i : list) {
        System.out.print(i+" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

[Demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/JKSO7q).

Comment: it works but how to show this ? Iterator<Integer> it = ArrayList.iterator();
while(it.hasNext())
{
    Integer a = it.next();
    System.out.println(a);
}

Comment: @user2458768 Take a look at the code that prints the array (look at the updated demo to see it run on ideone).

Comment: This is so counterintuitive and unreadable... Not criticizing you of course, criticizing Java.

Comment: Important Note: If you want to edit, lets say add an element to the `4, 5, 6` array using `group.get(1).add(999)`, it would not allow you to do so. This is because `Arrays.asList` will return an `AbstractList` instead of `ArrayList`. (Wrap it inside the constructor like `ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(4, 5, 6))` if you need to edit the lists. https://ideone.com/0WEVZ4

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
group.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3)));
```

The `ArrayList` has a `Collection` parameter in the constructor.

If you define the `group` as

```
List<List<Integer>> group = new ArrayList<>();
group.add(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
```